# dpkg "cycle found while processing triggers" libc-bin

Tags: linux, loops, triggers, dpkg

On a debian/ubuntu 16.04.01 system (gcloud-compute), I'm trying to remove and reinstall a screwed up postfix package without removing the package which depended on it (automysqlbackup) and forced it to be installed in the first place.  Since this is a running system, I'm trying not to disturb too much.  Attempting to see what will happen:

```
$ dpkg --simulate --purge postfix
dpkg: could not open log '/var/log/dpkg.log': Permission denied
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of postfix:
 bsd-mailx depends on default-mta | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package default-mta is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides default-mta is to be removed.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is to be removed.
 bsd-mailx depends on default-mta | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package default-mta is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides default-mta is to be removed.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is to be removed.
```

Since the mailer chain leading up to postfix is ok I want to leave it in place:

```
$ dpkg --simulate --ignore-depends bsd-mailx --purge postfix
dpkg: could not open log '/var/log/dpkg.log': Permission denied
(Reading database ... 171222 files and directories currently installed.)
Would remove or purge postfix (3.1.0-3ubuntu0.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
dpkg: cycle found while processing triggers:
 chain of packages whose triggers are or may be responsible:
  libc-bin -> libc-bin
 packages' pending triggers which are or may be unresolvable:
  libc-bin: ldconfig
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--purge):
 triggers looping, abandoned
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
```

I'm not well-versed in this and am working with a system I didn't create, so any help/pointers would be much appreciated. The libc-bin loop issue looks like something is screwed up and needs to be fixed before dealing with the postfix issue.  How to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install nullmailer, which removed postfix but still satisfied the default-mta and mail-transport-agent dependencies.  Then purge postfix, then install postfix:

```
  apt install nullmailer
  apt purge postfix
  apt install postfix
```

Many thanks to Peter Silva on the ubuntu user's group for suggesting this approach.